# Currying function in Javascript : use a parameter as a property in for-loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, currying

I am new to curry functions and am trying to use it.

But in the code I wrote, it throws Cannot read property 'absence'(which is `attr` in the function) of undefined".

Of course I need to read `attr`. Is there any way to get `attr` properly other than replacing `attr` as 'absence' instead?

```js
function check(arr){
  return(name) =>{
    return(attr) =>{
      return(key) =>{
        return(value) =>{
          var index = checkIndex(arr)(name);

          for(var i = 0; i < arr[index][attr].length; i+=1){ //"message": "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'absence' of undefined",
            if(arr[index][attr][i][key] === value){
              return i;
            }
          }
          return -1;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: When does it throw that error? May you show us how you’re calling it to get that error?

Comment: `var index = check(arr)(name);` this will set `index` to a have a function for a value, so `arr[index]` (i.e. `arr[someFunc]`) is `undefined` hence `arr[index][attr]` throws the error, because `attr` is not a member of `undefined`

Comment: @Nick oh, I need to rename that check(arr)(name). I have another function named check. and the error bumps on arr[index][attr][i][key].

Comment: In that case, you should do some debugging to determine what `index` is set to and check it against what you expect, as the outcome is still the same (`arr[index]` is `undefined`, so for example the `index` is out of range). As from what's shown here, given the correct input,  and a working `checkIndex`, I see no reason for it to not work

Comment: checkIndex is working properly thou... Thanks for your help

Comment: @JustDoo From what you've shown I don't see a problem, for someone to help they'll need more information (the `checkIndex` function body, some example test data, and an example of how you are calling the function at a minimum), from that they'll be able to see the issue, but from what's shown here there's no way to help (unless I'm missing something obvious)